# Finding $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\,dy\,dx$ for $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have no solution for this integral, please help

$$\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{x}\int\limits_0^x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\,dy\,dx \quad,\,n\in \mathbb N$$

Comment: Use geometric series.

Comment: Can you be more specific about that

Comment: The $y$ integrand is a geometric series.

Comment: I don't think so, y doesn't have conditions $0<y<1$

Comment: For $y \ne 1$ we have $$\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+...+y^{n-1}.$$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: As already said, $\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}y^k$

Comment: There are a couple things problematic with what you have stated. One $0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1$ so $y$ indeed has that condition. But even if that weren't the case, the geometric series formula still applies, the $|y| < 1$ condition is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+\cdots +y^{n-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}dy=x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}{3}+\cdots +\frac {x^n}{n}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac {1}{x}\int_0^x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}dy=1+\frac {x}{2}+\frac {x^2}{3}+\cdots +\frac {x^{n-1}}{n}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^1(\int_0^x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}dy)dx=\int_0^1(1+\frac {x}{2}+\frac {x^2}{3}+\cdots +\frac {x^{n-1}}{n})dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^1(\int_0^x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}dy)dx=1+\frac {1}{2^2}+\frac {1}{3^2}+\cdots +\frac {1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Switching the order of integrating of $x$ and $y$ gives
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{x}\int\limits_0^x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\,dy\,dx\\
&=&\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_y^1\frac{1}{x}\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\,dx\,dy=\int\limits_0^1\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}(-\ln y)dy\\
&=&-\int\limits_0^1(1+y+\cdots+y^{n-1})\ln ydy=1+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}.
\end{eqnarray}